# How to detect page loading errors in webview?

Tags: android, webview

I use the `onReceivedError` to detect all kinds of errors in my webview, but I want to detect if website has been blocked in their country `(net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` error). How do I do this?

```
  @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
        view.loadUrl("about:blank");//hide the error page
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "connection lost", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        findViewById(R.id.welcome).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        animEnabled = true;//enable welcome screen animation
        super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
    }
```

Comment: For example `if(description.equals("net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED")){}`, also call to super should be first:)

Answer (score 0):

The error code in the onReceived() call back will do the function you required. You just go through the webview error codes for accessing a specific type of error code.